# How to check Microsoft Exchange 2013 mailbox status database using c++

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

Want to check if mailbox database of Microsoft Exchange 2013 is mounted or not from c++ program that running under the windows service using system user.

Is there any way to know mailbox database status using c++ code? Is there any win32 API or WQL or Powershell command that I can run from c++ program?

I found the below exchange Powershell command to get the MailboxDatabase status but I need it in c++:

```
Get-MailboxDatabase -Identity "MailboxDatabase_1" -status | Format-List | findstr /X "Mounted"
```

Please let me know know if there is any more option for it.

Comment: You'll need a Windows service. While services can be installed and started from the command line, a normal command line program is not enough.

Comment: C# or C++? Decide.